# locationmanger wont stop

Tags: iphone, gps

i am starting GPS and then kept it on and make phone call within application using `openUrl` and then come back to application again and try to stop that GPS by calling `stopUpatingLocation` but GPS didn't stop.

Please give some solution to stop GPS.

**Code**

```
 app.locationManager.delegate=app;
 [app.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
 [app.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; //start gps
```

**then call hangup using code** `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] tel:@"number"];`

```
**Now after call hangup i need to stop that gps .... i have already written code below** 

[app.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
[app.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
app.locationManager=nil;
[app.locationManager release];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the related code, we can't help without any information about your code

Comment: can you show us your codes?

Comment: app.locationManager.delegate=app;
 [app.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
 [app.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; //start gps                then call hangup using code [[UIApplication sharedApplication] tel:@"number"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess just make a release for the location manager object.also make it a nil.

example::

```
[locationManager release];
locationManager=nil;
```

write these two lines in your dealloc.
Hope it helps